# Flash TextField won't accept all keyboard characters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I have an input text TextField in my movieclip instance but the text field just won't accept all my characters. I can enter for example character 'e', but pressing for example key 'p' won't work. Movie clip and it's TextField child is created in flash editor but I am creating an instance of this MC in my AS3 document class.

If I set keyboard event handler, it catches all the keyboard events, but the are just not shown in InputText field? I am using default Arial and Helvetica fonts. I even tried embedding them, but nothing actually helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a font embedding issue to me. Have you tried looking at the text field in Flash and making sure it's set to "Use System Fonts"?

Or, if you definitely need to embed it, you may need to specify a character range.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Not only you need to embed fonts (standard fonts as well), but you also need to select character ranges from embed window http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1207859/flashfonts.png. This is stupid, but it works.